# Summing values in a dynamically allocated 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I'm having trouble with my function that calculates color in my QuadTree. A 2-d Array is passed in and based on the's nodes offsets, a color is calculated by summing all the values and finding the average.  If the average is 0, color = 0 (white). If the average is 1 color = 1 (black).  And finally if the average is any value not 0 or 1 then color = 2 (grey). So if the node's row offset is 0 and its rows is 64 and cols is 64, the sum should sum up imgAry[0][0] when it gets to the end at imgAry[0][64] temp is incremented so it's imgAry[1][0] and so forth.  However it seems to be that the summing of the elements does not work. Is there faulty logic in the while and for loops for summing?

```
int computeColor(QuadTreeNode* node, int** imgAry)
{
    int sum;
    int temp = node->rowOffset;
    int temp2 = node->rowOffset + node->nrows;
    int total;
    int color;   

    while (temp <= temp2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < node->ncols; i++)
        {
            sum += imgAry[temp][i];
        }
        temp++;
    }

     cout << " Sum of the Array = " << sum << endl;

    total = node->nrows * node->ncols;
    cout << " Total elements in the Array = " << total << endl;

    if (sum  == 0)
    {
        color = 0;
    }

    else if (sum / total == 1)
    {
        color = 1;
    }

    else if (sum > 0)
    {
        color = 2;
    }

    cout << "Color is = " << color << endl; 
    return color;

}
```

Comment: First things first. `sum` is not initialized. I think it needs to be initialized to **0**.

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: What does it mean "_does not work_"?